# Verilog LED Blinking no syntax errors. why it is not blinking

Tags: verilog

I wrote the program for blink 8 raw LEDs and code has not any errors and it is properly loaded. But blinking LEDs is not happen properly.

I checked pin planner and it was correct and clock I used is 50MHz. I am using the DE10 lite board.

```vhdl
module LED_blink(clk,led);
    input clk;
    output reg[7:0] led;
    reg[31:0] count = 0;
    always @(posedge clk)
      begin
        count <= count + 1;
        led <= (count<50000000) ? 8'b11111111 : 0;
        count <= (count<50000000) ? count : 0;      
      end
endmodule
```

There are no error messages but it is not working the way I assumed.

Comment: Did you try to simulate and see if it's working? Can you post a screenshot of your pin planner including clock selection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should get the habit of simulating your code with a testbench before running it on an FPGA. But in this case even a simple [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) shows the errors.
When you execute `count<=(count<50000000)?count:0;` you override the previous `count<=count+1;`, thus the count will never increment.

This can be easily fixed by changing the 2 lines to:

```
count<=(count<50000000)?count+1:0;
```

The second problem is that `led` will be 0 only for one clock cycle (when `count` is equal to `50000000`), practically you won't see any blinking.
This can be easily fixed by changing the line to:

```
led<=(count<25000000)?8'b11111111:0;
```

Comment: @user11851100 glad to help, please accept the best answer, and take a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not syntactical, but there are some other problems in your code.

The first is the way you use *[nonblocking assignments](https://www.nandland.com/articles/blocking-nonblocking-verilog.html)* (`<=`). In your code, all assignments will only be evaluated at the end of the clock cycle. Thus, the first line of your always block (`count<=count+1`) does **not** affect the last line of your always block (`count<=(count<50000000)?count:0`). Also, only the last line will be evaluated.

The second problem is that you don't have a reset state for `count`. The value is never explicitly set to `0`, and you can therefore not know it's state.

If you fix these problems, there will be a third problem in your logic. You describe that your variable `led` should be `8'b11111111` if `count` is smaller than `50000000`. However, as soon as the counter exceeds this value, you reset it to `0`. In other words, your counter would *always* be smaller than `50000000`, and `led` would never be set to `0`.

I wrote down a small fix:

```
  module LED_blink(clk,led);
      input clk;
      output reg[7:0] led;

      reg[31:0]count=0;

      always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n)
      begin
          if (~rst_n) begin
              count <= 32'b0;
              led   <= 8'b0;
          end
          else begin
              count <= (count < 100000000) ? count + 1   : 0;
              led   <= (count < 50000000)  ? 8'b11111111 : 0;    
          end 
      end
  endmodule
```

Alternatively, you could write in your always block:

```
count <= (count  < 50000000) ? count + 1 : 0;
led   <= (count == 50000000) ? ~led      : led;
```

Comment: The reset for `count` is not a real problem in this situation. If the starting value is higher than the max value then it will be set back to `0` in the next clock cycle, otherwise, it will increase correctly. The only minor problem is that the very first iteration of the blinking process can be shorter.